# Vue.js updating text in a modal

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal and I am trying to dynamically update the text.

in my data

```
return {
         count: {
             value: 5
                },
            }
```

then I have a method

```
 bulkUserImport: function() {
                this.isLoading = true;
                let _this = this;
                axios.post('bulkUpdate', {'csv': this.importData})
                    .then((r) => console.log(r))
                    .then(() => this.isLoading = false)
                    .then(function() {
                        _this.$modal.show('dialog', {
                            title: 'Adding your new Clients',
                            text: `Jobscan is now provisioning your accounts, page will refresh in ${_this.count.value}  seconds.`,
                            buttons: [
                                {
                                    default: true,
                                    handler: () => _this.$emit('close'),
                                }
                            ]
                        });
                        _this.test()
                    })
                    .then(() => this.reloadClients());
            },
```

Then the test method

```
test: function(){
                if(this.count.value > 0){
                    this.count.value = this.count.value - 1;
                    console.log(this.count.value);
                    let temp = this;
                    setTimeout(function(count){
                        temp.test();
                    }, 1000);
                }
            },
```

In the text in the modal I have a variable `_this.count.value` that prints out 5.  Then I have a call to `_this.test()` to update the variable.

In `test()`. I console.log the results and the number does go down

[image]

However, it is not updating the `_this.count.value`  in the text.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is the modal

[image]

Comment: What `$modal` is that? Also, you would profit from using arrow functions (`() => {}`) instead of `function(){}`, you wouldn't need to use so much `_this` and `temp`s.

Comment: @acdcjunior, thanks for the tip about using arrow functions instead.  I added an image of the modal for $modal

Comment: I actually mean if $modal is the $bvModal, from the bootstrap-vue

Comment: @acdcjunior no it is not

Comment: Which one is it?